# Yosemite, double interface (eth/wifi) access a site through a specific interface

Tags: macos, networking, web, proxy, osx-yosemite

I have a macbook, connected with ethernet, and wifi. 
A site (lets call it facebook) is blocked on one of the interface (ethernet)
but is open on the other (wifi), on the other hand eth is better (fastest and more reliable than the wifi) so I use eth as a priority interface (on top of network preferences), but in this way there is no access to the blocked site.

I would know if there is a way to say to the operating system or browser or other
software components that it must use the connection of wifi if and only if a connection on :80 over eth fail. this would be perfect...or any other means to solve the problem..
It's a matter of configuring a proper proxy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could modify routing table to pass traffic to given host or network through chosen gateway.

List your routing table:

```
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway              Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.0.0.1             UGSc           15        0     en0
default            192.168.0.1          UGScI           1        0     en1
[...]
```

In this case `en1` is wifi. So to use wifi connection to a host x.x.x.x, route traffic to this host through `192.168.0.1` gateway:

```
sudo route add -host x.x.x.x 192.168.0.1
```

Or better add routing to entire network used by given service:

```
sudo route add -net x.x 192.168.0.1
```

The downside is that it may be difficult to determine an ultimate list of IPs, networks used by the service.

See man [route](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/route.8.html).